# Identity Server 4 Client sometime stuck on consent screen in load balancer environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, amazon-elb

Some times it works okay, but in many times it stucks on consent screen and after trying again and again it throws error:

> Error from RemoteAuthentication: Message contains error:
> 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'error_description is null',
> error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.. 2022-04-26 03:14:41.099 +00:00 [ERR]
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote
> login.  --->
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException:
> Message contains error: 'invalid_grant', error_description:
> 'error_description is null', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage
> tokenEndpointRequest)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()

Identity Code

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToDbContext<DataprotectionContext>()
    .SetApplicationName("authapplication");

services
    .AddDefaultIdentity<AuthUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
//services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache();

X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("****", "****");
services
    .AddIdentityServer(
        options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext =
            builder => builder.UseMySql(
                connectionString,
                ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString),
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetName().Name));
    })
    .AddAspNetIdentity<AuthUser>()
    .AddSigningCredential(cert)
    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

services.AddAuthentication();
```

Client Code

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "cookies";
    })
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = serviceSettings.Value.Auth.TrimEnd('/');

    options.ClientId = "auth-admin-client";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
    };

    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
});
```

I have used this in configure for client and server:

```
app.Use((context, next) => { context.Request.Scheme = "https"; return next(); });
var fordwardedHeaderOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
};
fordwardedHeaderOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
fordwardedHeaderOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();
app.UseForwardedHeaders(fordwardedHeaderOptions);
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

Comment: "error: 'invalid_grant'" So.... (guessing a little) the `&grant_type=` parameter was lost? (see https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/authorization-code-request/)

Comment: `Some times it works okay, but in many times it stucks`  so how do you set the load balancer environment? Did your code work well when you test in your local side? I mean if this is a code issue or a configuration issue.

Comment: yes locally it is working fine

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).